# What's the best way of using a container in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to achieve the following layout in CSS Grid.

[image: a busy cat]

Notice how row "C" has a blue background that is *full width* but the content inside it is wrapped, and not full width. But I don't know what's the most optimal way of achieving this?

So here's my code:

```
container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1fr 1fr 0.5fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "A A A A"
    ". B B ."
    "C C C C"
    ". D D .";
}
```

What I've tried:

1. I've tried 16.66% padding to both sides for row "C".
2. I've tried making the row C be a Grid itself. Inside it, I'd have columns 0.5fr, 1fr, 1fr, 0.5fr. But this is lot of repeated code, and is lot of work for a simple thing.

What is the most CSS Grid way of approaching this? All the tutorials I've seen, doesn't seem to cover this special case.

Comment: but `C` is full-width according to your `grid-template-areas` already right?

Comment: Yes. C itself is full width. The content inside it is not. I could make C have property `display: Grid;`, or I could just manually add paddings. But I'm not sure if there are better ways.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to make `C` *span* the two columns in the center which seems in line with your layout and use a *pseudo element* that takes care of the background

- add `grid-row: 3` and `grid-column: 1 / -1` to the *pseudo element* to place it in the same position as `C` but spanning the whole width
- push it to the back using `z-index: -1` and `position: relative`

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1fr 1fr 0.5fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "A A A A"
    ". B B ."
    ". C C ."
    ". D D .";
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 3;
  background: cadetblue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.A {
  grid-area: A;
  background: pink;
  
}
.B {
  grid-area: B;
  background: orange;
}

.C {
  grid-area: C;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.D {
  grid-area: D;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="D">D</div>
</div>
```